# Non-recursive Most Efficient Big-O Permutation Alghoritm Python3 (non-built-in)

Tags: python-3.x, big-o, permutation, memory-efficient

Hi Guys For my Data Structure assignment I have to find the most efficient way (big-o wise) to calculate permutations of a list of objects.

I found recursive examples on the web but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way; I tried my own code but then I realized that when I count the number of possible permutations I'm actually making my algorithm O(!n). Any suggestions? .-.

```py
from random import sample
import time
start = time.time()

testList = list(x for x in range(7))
print('list lenght: %i objects' % len(testList))

nOfPerms = 1
for i in range(1,len(testList)+1):
    nOfPerms *= i
print('number of permutations:', nOfPerms)

listOfPerms = []
n = 1
while n <= nOfPerms:
    perm = tuple(sample(testList, len(testList)))

    listOfPerms.append(perm)
    permutations = set(listOfPerms)

    if len(permutations) == len(listOfPerms):
        n += 1
    else:
        del(listOfPerms[-1])

end = time.time() - start
print('time elapsed:', end)
```

OUTPUT:

```
list lenght: 7 objects
number of permutations: 5040
time elapsed: 13.142292976379395
```

If instead of 7 I put 8 or 9, or 10, those are the number of permutations (I won't show the time cause it's taking too long):

```
list lenght: 8 objects
number of permutations: 40320

list lenght: 9 objects
number of permutations: 362880

list lenght: 10 objects
number of permutations: 3628800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will be the best you can do. Generating the number of permutations of a list generates n! permutations. As you need to generate them all this is also how much time it will take (O(n!)). What you could try to do is to make it a python generator function so you will always only generate exactly as many as you need instead of precalculating them all and storing them in memory. If you want an example of this i could give you one.

Im sorry this might be a quite negative answer. It's a good question but im pretty sure this is about the best that you can do, asymptotically. You could optimize the code itself a bit to use less instructions but in the end that wont help too much.

Edit:

This is a python implementation of Heap's algorithm which i promised
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) generating N! permutations where the generation of every one permutation takes amortized O(1) time and which uses O(n) space complexity (by alteri

```py
def permute(lst, k=None):
    if k == None:

        k = len(lst)

    if k == 1:
        yield lst
    else:
        yield from permute(lst, k-1)

        for i in range(k-1):

            if i % 2 == 0:
                #even
                lst[i], lst[k-1] = lst[k-1], lst[i]
            else:
                #odd
                lst[0], lst[k-1] = lst[k-1], lst[0]
            yield from permute(lst, k-1)


for i in permute([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Yeah If you can post an example with a generator, that would be useful, anyway, I found the code that python uses in the built-in function `itertools.permutation()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

It seems to me that their bigO is O(n)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336881/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-permutations It is only O(n) for every item you ask from it.

Comment: I added the implementation

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I will wait to accept your answer because I'm curious if someone come up with a solution that is not O(!n) ;-)

Comment: Not a problem friend, and dont worry about the acceptance for now. Just don't forget about it as it's useful for other people to know. Good luck with your datastructure assignment. I just finished a similar course too :)